# Use case for initialized extern variable

Tags: c++, extern

I realized that I can *define* an `extern` variable, like:

**source.cpp**

```
extern int i = 42; // definition, can very well just remove the `extern`
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>

extern int i; // declaration

int  main()
{
    std::cout << i << std::endl;
}
```

I can then compile and link the program,

```
g++ main.cpp source.cpp
```

and it runs and correctly displays `42`. The warning I get is

> warning: 'i' initialized and declared 'extern' (gcc)
>
> warning: 'extern' variable has an initializer (clang)

Using `int i = 42;` in `source.cpp` has exactly the same overall effect.

**My question**: is there any non-trivial use case for variables *defined* `extern` (not just declared then defined in another translation unit)? Is such a definition even standard compliant?

Comment: `extern const int i = 42;`

Comment: @KerrekSB Ohhh yes, indeed, can you please write an answer so I can accept it? It completely slipped out of my mind that `const` needs an initialization. But still not completely clear, why `const int i = 42;` in `source.cpp` doesn't work and produces an undefined symbol?

Comment: OK, done. It's about linkage; what you wrote doesn't produce external linkage.

Comment: makes perfect sense now, thanks, kept forgetting that `const` has internal linkage.

Comment: Well, `const` on variables at namespace scope, yes...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `extern` specifier is useful in conjunction with variables that would have internal linkage without it, such as constants at namespace scope:

**a.cpp:**

```
extern const int n = 10;  // external linkage
```

**b.cpp:**

```
int main()
{
    extern const int n;   // finds the n defined in the other TU
    return n;
}
```