# C2372 Redefinition; different types of indirection

Tags: c++, scope, declaration, definition, linkage

I am trying to define/declare a int array varible in one of my other files.

**Other_file.h**

```
#pragma once
extern int* Test = new int[2]; // <- Here I declare(at least by my understanding)
```

**Other_file.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Other file.h"

int* Test[2]; // <- Line that causes error...
```

Then the **Main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Other file.h"

int main() {
    std::cout << Test;
    return 0;
}
```

Each time I get this error: `Error   C2372   'Test': redefinition; different types of indirection | Other File.cpp | line 4` 
FYI I use MSVC 2019.

Comment: As soon as you initialize, you go from declaration to definition and undo the `extern`.

Comment: Ok thanks, that is good to know

Comment: I should say mostly undo the `extern`.  You do have a definition rather than a declaration, but the external linkage remains.

Comment: [Here's a discussion of the above and a possible use-case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32872607/use-case-for-initialized-extern-variable).

Answer (score 2):

```
extern int* Test = new int[2]; // <- Here I declare(at least by my understanding)
```

No, that's a definition. This would be the declaration:

```
extern int* Test; // note, no value
```

As well, the two declarations are incompatible, which is what the error is trying to tell you. `int*[2]` and `int*` are completely different.

Comment: Great that worked just had to add ```Test[]``` instead of ```Test```. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Where did you add `Test[]`?

Answer (score 2):

This declaration

```
extern int* Test = new int[2];
```

also a definition of a pointer with external linkage because the pointer is initialized.

Then in the source file `"Other_file.cpp"` you redefined the name `Test` as an array of two elements of the type `int *`.

```
#include "Other file.h"

int* Test[2];
```

So the compiler issues an error.

In fact the above code snippet is equivalent to

```
extern int* Test = new int[2];
int* Test[2];
```

If you want to declare a pointer then in the header `"Other file.h"` declare it like

```
extern int* Test;
```

and then in the source file `"Other_file.cpp"` write

```
#include "Other file.h"

int *Test = new int[2];
```